# Travic CI status image nodejs

Tags: node.js, travis-ci

I am searching for Travis CI ability to show number of tests passed (related to each node.js version).
Currently it is only possible to see the [build|passing] image.

It should be something like
    [npm test 0.10.13 | 3/4]
    [npm test 0.11.16 | 4/4]
    [npm test 0.12.3 | 2/4]

Comment: at the moment I will not get a different image target if I am selecting the sub-jobs,

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible, you can only see [build|passed], [build|failed], [build|error], etc.

Comment: in that case the ability of testing against all node versions but showing users the build state of only all together isn't useful. It is a really bad feature leak !!!